# SQL SUM in PIVOT that uses MAX

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, pivot-table

I am trying to get the SUM of 2 or more TIME fields within my PIVOT table, however because the  SUM does not work with characters (converted so I can show EstimatedTime / ActualTime), I'm having difficulty.

The code below -

```
DECLARE @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX);
DECLARE @query AS NVARCHAR(MAX);

select @cols = STUFF((SELECT distinct ',' + ID + ',' + QUOTENAME(Name)
                  FROM JobPhases
                  FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
                 ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
                    , 1, 1, '');

SELECT @query = 'SELECT * FROM    
(   
    SELECT j.JobID, c.Registration as ''Reg.'', p.Name, 
    CAST(MAX(j.EstimatedTime) as VARCHAR(MAX)) + ''/'' +
    CAST(MAX(j.ActualTime) as VARCHAR(MAX)) as [x]
    FROM    JobDetails  AS j
    INNER JOIN JobPhases p ON p.ID = j.PhaseId
    INNER JOIN Jobs job on job.ID = j.JobID
    INNER JOIN Cars c on job.CarID = c.ID
    WHERE (job.Status = 1 or job.Status = 0)
    GROUP BY c.Registration, p.Name, j.JobID
) JobDetails
PIVOT
(   MAX(x)
    FOR Name IN (' + @cols + ')
) pvt'

execute(@query);
```

Generates -

```
JobID | Reg.     | P13$ | Repair and Reshape                | P15$ | Refit Stripped Parts
1065  | BJ11 2VT | NULL | 01:00:00.0000000/01:54:10.5387526 | NULL | NULL
```

Tables -

```
**JobDetails**
ID - PK Auto increment
JobID - Int (Joined to Jobs table)
PhaseID - String (joined to JobPhases table)
EstimatedTime - time(7)
ActualTime time(7)

**JobPhases****
ID - PK String
Name - VarChar(150)
```

The problem in this example is there are 2 JobDetails for JobID 1065 -

```
ID | JobID | PhaseID | EstimatedTime    | ActualTime 
25 | 1065  | P13$    | 01:00:00.0000000 | 01:54:10.5387526
26 | 1065  | P13$    | 00:30:00.0000000 | 00:00:00.0000000
```

So, the correct result should be (Note the 1:30 in the Repair & Reshape) -

```
JobID | Reg.     | P13$ | Repair and Reshape                | P15$ | Refit Stripped Parts
1065  | BJ11 2VT | NULL | 01:30:00.0000000/01:54:10.5387526 | NULL | NULL
```

Any ideas how I can get the total EstimatedTime for all rows for each phase id?

Thanks!

Comment: Pivots aren't my strong side, but shouldn't changing `CAST(MAX(j.EstimatedTime) as VARCHAR(MAX)) + ''/'' +` to `CAST(SUM(j.EstimatedTime) as VARCHAR(MAX)) + ''/'' +` work?

Comment: This does not work because SUM cannot be used with varchar. Nice try though :)

Comment: EstimatedTime is a decimal according to your schema...?

Comment: Apologies, I have set correct. It is actually time(7)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Summing `TIME` columns isn't straight forward, what you need is to rewrite your line;

```
CAST(MAX(j.EstimatedTime) as VARCHAR(MAX)) + ''/'' +
```

to something like (the untested)

```
CAST(CAST(DATEADD(ms, SUM(DATEDIFF(ms, '0:00:00', j.EstimatedTime)), 
                 '00:00:00') AS TIME) AS VARCHAR(MAX)) + ''/'' +
```